# Problems with .x() in dc.js barCharts

Tags: dc.js

I am doing my first interactive visualization using dc.js. I have come to a hard stop over a dc.barChart() attribute that I cannot seem with the answers I find here og on google. I will start the code from the `crossfilter()`function. I am able to create dc.rowCharts() so I highly doubt that it is a malformed .json problem

```
    var ndx = crossfilter(salgsTransaksjonene);

//Define Dimensions
var kundeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["CustomerName"]; });    

//Calculate metrics
var OmsetningKunder = kundeDim.group().reduceSum(function(fact) { return fact.TotalAmount;});

    //Charts
var toppChart = dc.barChart("#topp-20-bar-chart");

toppChart
    .width(950)
    .height(240)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
    .dimension(kundeDim)
    .group(topp20OmsetningKunder)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .elasticY(true)
    .yAxis().ticks(4)
```

When it comes to the .x() attribute I have tried the following

```
//      .isOrdinal(true)
//      .xUnitCount(20)
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal.domain(salgsTransaksjonene.map(function (d) {return d.CustomerName; })))
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal()); 

//      .isOrdinal(true)
//      .xUnitCount(20)
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal());
```

The errors I get is mostly the same; `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

and various combinations of the above attributes, but to no avail. Any Ideas about what could be wrong is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a .domain with your ordinal values like this.
Also I've seen the order of the declarations to be of importance.

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['cat1','cat2','cat3']))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

here is a full working barchart for your inspiration.

```
chart11
    .width(xxx)
    .height(xxx)
    .margins(xxx)
    .dimension(xxx)
    .group(xxx)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .centerBar(false)
    .transitionDuration(transitionDuration)
    .elasticY(true)
    .gap(1)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .yAxis().ticks(2)
    ;
```

Comment: Right.  Also see https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis